# Layer Mask is gone while creating clipping path

Tags: gimp, plugin

I have come up with a gimp plugin which is supposed to create a clipping path along with the layer mask. It does if we check the output in gimp 2.10.22. But when I open the output with photoshop cc 2019, the layer mask is gone!

Here is the problem and all the associated scripts and files-

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14nklxAf454TiJlHtyO-14J_sK2Cua951?usp=sharing

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Note: We are open to a feasible bounty for this if required.

Shamim Hossain
sparrowmtm@gmail.com

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Layer masks are non-standard in TIFFs.  Adobe Photoshop supports them when the TIFF is made in Photoshop, but other applications probably won't support this.  GIMP will apply a layer mask as an alpha channel when you export as TIFF. If you want to preserve a layer mask so you can open it and edit it in Photoshop, you can export as PSD from GIMP.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, Billy. It means a lot.